# VPN: Network initialization failed

Tags: wireless, vpn

Suddenly my VPN (provided by VPN.ht) started to disconnect with the *Authentication error: network initialization failed* while downloading a torrent. I am able to start a download, but after a while it just disconnects. At times the VPN won't even connect without dowloading a torrent. There's obviously nothing wrong on the ISN's side, as - without the VPN - downloads are good. The VPN.ht support seem clueless, resetting my password and such.

My torrent client is using port 8889. Just for the sake of testing, I switched to 8898 and after a while the VPN disconnects again.

I'm aware there was a similar bug some time ago regarding 18.04, but disabling the Bluetooth, which seemed to be a credible solution, didn't work for me.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, 64-bit OS, a WiFi network, using qBittorrent for torrents.

Comment: What happens if you choose a different VPN server?

Comment: I don’t believe my provider has any other.

Comment: Go to https://vpn.ht/servers and select any servers located outside of the US.

Comment: My bad: of course they do. Sorry for that.

Comment: I tried Mexico, Lithuania, Hong Kong, France. No changes, it’s still disconnecting after a torrent kicks in.

Comment: In `terminal` type `sudo openvpn /path_to/insert_my_filename_here.ovpn`. Retry. Turn off your firewall. Retry. Turn your firewall back on.

Comment: I’m not using a firewall or an OVPN file. I entered the VPN config from https://billing.vpn.ht/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/12/How-to-set-up-VPN-on-Linux-with-PPTP-.html

Comment: If that doesn't work, go to the VPN server page, and download a config file for the US that uses a TCP port 80/443 and retry.

Comment: You should be using this... for OpenVPN... https://billing.vpn.ht/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/16/Linux-Ubuntu-Network-Manger-OpenVPN.html

Comment: It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Just to briefly explain myself: Ubuntu have changed the default VPN config app. The new version doesn’t let you use a OVPN file or a certificate. To do that, you need to delete the default VPN preset and *add* a new one.

Comment: re: "doesn’t let you use a OVPN file or a certificate"... if you import the .ovpn file that you get from vpn.ht, you'll get all of the correct settings, and a CA cert.

Comment: It does - once you create a new VPN connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP was connecting to vpn.ht VPN via manual PPTP configuration, and having difficulty.

vpn.ht distributes configuration files as .ovpn (OpenVPN). .ovpn files can be downloaded from their [servers](https://vpn.ht/servers) page.

OP should be configuring as OpenVPN using these .ovpn files. Check [here](https://billing.vpn.ht/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/16/Linux-Ubuntu-Network-Manger-OpenVPN.html) for instructions.